# Jquery DIV element Scroll top and down?

Tags: jquery, html, height, scroll, max

I have a div and some buttons. I have fixed the div with a particular height, and i have hidden the scrollbar. By clicking on a button I need scroll the div to the end of the line.
for that I used `$("#divid").height()` & `$("#divid").offset().height` functions to get the entire height of the div but it returns what I have specified in the css, how to get the entire height of the DIV.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to get the height of the div when the page loads, in javascript, then set it's height in javascript after you have the full height

Answer (score -1):

Is that what you are looking for?

http://yelotofu.com/2008/10/jquery-how-to-tell-if-youre-scroll-to-bottom/